# add style to <p>

Tags: html, css

I want to change the font of the `<p>` tag in HTML so I tried:

```
<p style="font-family:'Myriad Pro','sans-serif'; font-size:10.0pt; color:#BE2D0F; ">
```

But it doesn't work, any suggestion how to do that? I need to change the font to this font color, font, and font type.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Dt8yg/). Are you sure you have Myriad Pro installed on your system? Are you seeing any style change at all?

Comment: Your code does work in my browser.

Comment: **What** doesn't work?  All three properties?  Just one?  what?  Also, what's the HTML context?  Are you surrounding the styled text by including a closing tag `</p>`?

Comment: Why are we up-voting this vague and incomplete question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is correct.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/bcEKb/

Note that this only sets the style for that single `<p>` tag.  To set the style of EVERY `<p>` tag, you need to use a separate stylesheet or put it in `<head>` like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type = "text/css">
            p
            {
                font-family: "Myriad Pro", "sans-serif";
                font-size: 10pt;
                color: #BE2D0F;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This paragraph has the style applied.</p>
        <p>So does this one.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/G6TKe/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a external CSS file, ensure that you put a class for p if you want it to be used on EVERY paragraph, if its just the one paragraph then just put the code inline (as you have done and it works)

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the font names without the single quotes.

Comment: Font names with spaces must be quoted.

Comment: The second font doesn't need it, but the first one does, because it has a space in its name.